# Infix Not enough information to infer type variable T

Tags: kotlin, infix-notation

what a difference does make the "**.**" for an infix function in Kotlin?

Here is my example of java "try catch" DSL usage:

*this compiles OK*

```
    try_(openFile("1"), openFile("2")) { (streamIn, streamOut) ->
        doMyStuffIfYouKnowWhatImTalkingAbout(streamIn, streamOut)
    } catch { error: NullPointerException ->
        print("Kotlin has a null pointer exception ;)")
    } catch { error: RuntimeException ->
        print("Bad things happen, take care")
    } finally {
        print("It's time to go home")
    }
```

*this compiles OK*

```
    try_(openFile("1"), openFile("2")) { (streamIn, streamOut) ->
        doMyStuffIfYouKnowWhatImTalkingAbout(streamIn, streamOut)
    }.catch<NullPointerException> {
        // this compiles OK
    }.catch<RuntimeException> {
        // this compiles OK
    } finally {
        // this compiles OK
    }
```

***this DOESN'T compile***

```
    try_(openFile("1"), openFile("2")) { (streamIn, streamOut) ->
        doMyStuffIfYouKnowWhatImTalkingAbout(streamIn, streamOut)
    } catch<NullPointerException> {
        // this DOESN'T compile due to Not enough information to infer type variable T
    } catch<RuntimeException> {
        // this DOESN'T compile due to Not enough information to infer type variable T
    } finally {
        // this compiles
    }
```

Here is an implementation of it where the infix function **catch** is defined:

```
inline fun <T : AutoCloseable> try_(vararg resources: T, block: (Array<out T>) -> Unit): Throwable? = try {
    block(resources)
    null
} catch (error: Throwable) {
    error
} finally {
    resources.forEach {
        try {
            it.close()
        } catch (ignore: Throwable) {

        }
    }
}

inline infix fun <reified T : Throwable> Throwable?.catch(block: (T) -> Unit) =
if (this is T) {
    block(this)
    null
} else this

inline infix fun Throwable?.finally(block: () -> Unit) = block()
```

So why does `}.catch<RuntimeException> {` works but this `} catch<RuntimeException> {` doesn't?

Comment: The second is unsupported syntax for an infix function. If it can't infer the type, you can't use it as an infix.

Comment: Have you got a source for that @Tenfour04?

Comment: No, but even the simplest possible infix with generic type will complain if you try to use it that way: `infix fun <T> Any.foo(other: Any) = Any() as T`. Also, that kind of syntax goes against the intended use of infix (very simple combinations of two objects). Using it for complicated chains or higher-order functions in my opinion and probably the opinion of the language designers creates unclear code.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes I agree! Just wondered whether it had been mentioned officially.

Comment: Don't see any limitations for this (infix call with type parameters) in language spec (nor in [infix function call](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#infix-function-call) section, neither in [call with specified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#call-with-specified-type-parameters)). Since infix function declaration with generic parameters is not forbidden, it looks like a compiler bug. I'd suggest to submit this as issue on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT